# How can I execute a shell command in my rvm enviroment?

Tags: ruby, shell, rvm

I'm trying to execute shell commands from Ruby, but in order to these commands to work properly a RVM environment has to be selected. I don't find the way to do so.

For example I'm trying:

```
require "rubygems"
require "rvm"

RVM.gemset_use! "ruby-1.9.3-p286@my_project"
%x[rails s]
```

But looks like the rvm environment is not been loaded because the gems are not found.

#### Update

The only way I'm seeing is

```
%x[source /Users/fguillen/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p286@my_project && rails s]`
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you please try `x[rvm use 1.9.3-p286@my_project]` before `x[rails s]`?

Comment: May be you have a type in `ruby-1.9.3-p286@my_project`, no need of `ruby-` prefix

Comment: Why do you want to set the RVM environment from within Ruby?

Comment: @Stefan I don't want it.. I just needed in order to the further commands are executed in the proper rvm environemnt and can user the proper ruby version and the proper gemset

Comment: @maximus I tried the `rvm use ...` and I got the error `RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.`

Comment: looks like we are on right track, just put `%x[source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm]` before rvm use. `~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` is path to your rvm script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [rvm-with](https://github.com/mpapis/rvm-with) is just what you are looking for. It would allow you to do:

```
require "rvm/with"
RVM.with "1.9.3-o286@my_project" do |r|
  puts r.execute "rails s"
end
```

Comment: It looks pretty cool (+1 for that), but it is not working for me.. it throws an error, at some point it executes this `ruby_version_path=$( rvm ruby-1.9.3-p286@my_project do rvm env -- --path ) && source $ruby_version_path` and fails with `-bash: export: No such file or directory`

Comment: Works now!, the problem was the `rvm` version I was using... too old.